# Regarding factory design pattern through reflection

Tags: java, design-patterns

I was doing R&D on factory pattern I have developed the below code ,rite now I know the subclasses are  Dog and Cat , but please advise me what to do if the same thing I want to achieve through reflection by passing the class name in main.java

```
    public abstract class Animal {
    public abstract String makeSound();
}

public class Dog extends Animal {

    @Override
    public String makeSound() {
        return "Woof";
    }

}

public class Cat extends Animal {

    @Override
    public String makeSound() {
        return "Meow";
    }

}

public class AnimalFactory {

    public Animal getAnimal(String type) {
        if ("canine".equals(type)) {
            return new Dog();
        } else {
            return new Cat();
        }
    }

}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnimalFactory animalFactory = new AnimalFactory();

        Animal a1 = animalFactory.getAnimal("feline");
        System.out.println("a1 sound: " + a1.makeSound());

        Animal a2 = animalFactory.getAnimal("canine");
        System.out.println("a2 sound: " + a2.makeSound());
    }

}
```

Please advise it how I can add reflection functionality into it so that I don't need to even determine the type , just pass the class name in the main java and object of that subclass get created

Comment: Hi Folks, please advise for this..!!

Answer (score 2):

For this to work, your `Cat` and `Dog` classes must be in their own files in the package `your.package` and have default constructors:

```
public class AnimalFactory {
    public Animal getAnimal(String type) {
        return (Animal) Class.forName("your.package." + type).newInstance();
    }
}
```