# Regarding factory design pattern through reflection implemented in java

Tags: java, oop, reflection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regarding factory design pattern through reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10417688/regarding-factory-design-pattern-through-reflection)

I was doing R&D on factory pattern I have developed the below code.  Right now I know the subclasses are `Dog` and `Cat`, but please advise me.  What to do if I want to achieve the same thing through reflection by passing the class name in `main.java`?

### Animal

```
public abstract class Animal {
    public abstract String makeSound();
}
```

### Dog

```
public class Dog extends Animal {

    @Override
    public String makeSound() {
        return "Woof";
    }
}
```

### Cat

```
public class Cat extends Animal {

    @Override
    public String makeSound() {
        return "Meow";
    }
}
```

### AnimalFactory

```
public class AnimalFactory {

    public Animal getAnimal(String type) {
        if ("canine".equals(type)) {
            return new Dog();
        } else {
            return new Cat();
        }
    }
}
```

### Main

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnimalFactory animalFactory = new AnimalFactory();

        Animal a1 = animalFactory.getAnimal("feline");
        System.out.println("a1 sound: " + a1.makeSound());

        Animal a2 = animalFactory.getAnimal("canine");
        System.out.println("a2 sound: " + a2.makeSound());
    }
}
```

Please advise it how I can add reflection functionality into it so that I don't need to even determine the type, just pass the class name in the main java and object of that subclass gets created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass the fullyqualified name of the class, you can instantiate them as following:

```
return (Animal) Class.forName(fullyQualifiedClassName).newInstance();
```

To avoid ClassCastException, you could test that the returned class of `Class.forName()` is indeed a subclass of `Animal` before invoking `newInstance()`. Use `isAssignableFrom` for that.

Comment: @Guillaume..what other changes need to be done in main.java please advise

Comment: @user1370546 it all depends, either you throw the possible exceptions, and then you will have to catch them wherever you invoke the factory, or you catch them all in the factory method. You also need to cast the returned value of `newInstance()` to (Animal) so that the factory method is ok. Of course, you need to invoke the factory method with the appropriate class names.

Comment: Is this guy pulling our nose?? See comment he left to my answer.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yeah I saw that.

Answer (score 2):

```
public Animal getAnimal(String clName) {
  try {
      return (Animal) Class.forName(clName).newInstance();
  } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for that but corresponding changes also need to be done in main.java ..it such as Animal a1 = animalFactory.getAnimal("Cat");
  System.out.println("a1 sound: " + a1.makeSound());

Comment: Then explain your words: "just pass the class name in the main java and object of that subclass get created"

Comment: It works ...Animal a1 = animalFactory.getAnimal("FactoryDesignPattern.Cat");
  System.out.println("FactoryDesignPattern.Cat: " + a1.makeSound());